# Verizon and I disagree about the duration of a contract. Do I have any recourse?

Tags: united-states, billing, contracts

A little less than a year ago, I purchased an iPad with service from Verizon Wireless and getting what I was told was a one-year contract for $100 off of a device of just under $1000 of the price. (Note that the pricing is a good distance from "Two years' contract and we'll give you a free device.") I called and checked, and they believe that I signed a "standard two-year contract."

Do I have any options to contest that I signed a two-year contract for $100 off a $1000 device? Can I ask to see their copies of the contract that they believe I signed for two years?

Comment: This is what you don't believe what you're *told* the terms of a contract are, and get a written copy for yourself...

Comment: Do you have a copy of a contract that you signed for one year?

Comment: Unless you have the original contract -- preferably with their signature or receipt or something else which can show when/where you and they agreed to it -- you're sorta stuck unless you're willing to take it to court. You can certainly ask for a copy; they might be willing to pull out your signed contract and send you a copy (possibly for some processing fee, hopefully not entirely unreasonable)... but I don't think they're actually obligated to produce it unless this gets to the courts.

Comment: Take this with a brick of salt, but having experience with their B2B operations, and some consumer billing, a copy of the contract they have should be available by mail if you call their billing dept. As already noted, there may be a processing fee involved. Failing that, talk to a store to see if they can provide you a printed copy. Either way, you'll have something to compare with your original. Finally, don't forget that if you added or upgraded ANY device attached to the account (not the iPad), that often extends the contract (default of a two-year renewal).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a copy of the contract showing the one year contract, you should be able to enforce that by sending it to Verizon or if that doesn't work, filing in small claims court for the cost to you.

If you don't have a copy of the contract, request the copy from Verizon.   If you can't produce a copy that shows 1 year, I think you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have much legal recourse unless you can produce the original contract. However, most cell phone company contracts include legal terms saying that you can get out of the contract if they change the terms. Quite frequently, they'll make some really minor modification of the terms (a small additional fee, changing data usage parameters, etc.) which basically gives all their customers a "get out of contract free" card. You could always check to see if they've made any changes over time.

Cell companies will also let you out of the contract if you want to use the device in an area not covered by their service. For example, when a relative in my family went to college, they had no service. We simply showed them a verification of her enrollment and a coverage map of the college and BOOM, out of the contract.